# Как сохранить форму отношение FK к info_court

Tags: python, django

def court_event_add(request, pk):
"""Создание-добавление  нового судебного события"""

```
accident = Accident.objects.get(id=pk)
accident_pk = accident.pk
court_info = accident.court_info.info_courts.all()
for item in court_info:
    item.pk, item.info_court
    print(item.pk, item.info_court, item.info_court_id, item.worker)
court_info_id = accident.court_info.pk
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CourtForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print('CourtForm', form)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        Как правильно сохранить отношения FK form к info_court
        form.info_court.pk = court_info_id
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
CourtForms = CourtForm()
template_name = 'dist/court/event/read_court_add_event.html'
data = {'court_info': court_info,
        'court': CourtForms,
        'court_list': court_list,
        'accident_pk': accident_pk
        }
```

models.py
class InfoCourt(models.Model):
"""Информация о деле"""

```
status = models.ForeignKey(
    Status,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    verbose_name='Статус  дела',
    related_name='court_status',
    default=None,
    blank=True,
    null=True
                           )
judge = models.ForeignKey(
    judge,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    verbose_name='Судья',
    related_name='court_judge',
    default=None,
    blank=True,
    null=True
                           )

case_number = models.CharField(
    max_length=24,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Номер Судебного дела')
uid_number = models.CharField(
    max_length=26,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='УИД Судебного дела')
data_reg = models.DateField(
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Дата регистрации дела')
location = models.ForeignKey(
    ListCourt,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    default=None,
    related_name='location', verbose_name='Место  ')
message = models.TextField(
    max_length=50000,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Результат события Коментарий')
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.uid_number

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Информация дела"
    verbose_name_plural = "Информация дела"
    ordering = ['-created']

def get_list(self):
    return self.location.name
```

class Court(models.Model):
"""Таблица оперций связанных с  судебным процессом """

```
info_court = models.ForeignKey(
    InfoCourt,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='info_courts',
    blank=True,
    verbose_name='Список юр.оперций '
        )

procedure = models.ForeignKey(
    Procedure,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='procedure',
    verbose_name='Наименование события')
worker = models.ForeignKey(
    worker,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='worker',
    verbose_name='Отв-ный')
data_finish = models.DateField(
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Срок исполнения С')
date_start = models.DateTimeField(
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Начало исполнения С')
date_stop = models.DateTimeField(
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Завершения исполнения С')
akt_end = models.ForeignKey(
    ListEnd,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    default=None,
    related_name='akt_end',
    verbose_name='Событие утверждения')
time_stop = models.DateField(
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Время завершение операции ')
file_paste = models.FileField(
    upload_to='upload/Courtdoc/',
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='"Файл прикрепленный')
curt_hall = models.CharField(
    max_length=24,
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Номер кабинета заседания')
message = models.CharField(
    max_length=50000,
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name='Результат,коментарий события ')
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.procedure

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Оперция судопроизводства"
    verbose_name_plural = "Оперции судопроизводства"
    ordering = ['created']
```

Comment: print(form)                                                                                                                                                CourtForm <tr><th><label for="id_info_court">Список юр.оперций :</label></th><td><select name="info_court" id="id_info_court">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="48">345435435</option>

  <option value="47">5435435</option> , этому полю нужно назначить значение из списка?

Comment: А показывать свои модели, чтобы было лучше видно где у вас поле со связью fk

Comment: a так все верно form.info_court = значение. Если info_count  - это поле связи в моделе.

Comment: Добавил модели..

Comment: Я так и делал, form.info_court = court_info_id, где court_info_id = значение  id court_info (2), он создает форму но не  отношение не делает к родителю(

Comment: а вот так попробуйте form.info_court.id

Comment: 'CourtForm' object has no attribute 'info_court'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/court/court-event-add/8/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'CourtForm' object has no attribute 'info_court'

Comment: info_courts вместо info_court

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое банальное решение:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CourtForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print('CourtForm', form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.cleaned_data["info_court"]=court_info
            form.save()
 print(form.cleaned_data)
 {'info_court': <InfoCourt: 345435435>, 'procedure': <Procedure: 
 Исполнительный лист>, 'worker': <worker:  Вика Попова>, 
 'data_finish': None, 'date_start': None, 'date_stop': None, 
 'akt_end': <ListEnd: В процессе>, 'time_stop': None, 
 'file_paste': None, 'curt_hall': '22221', 'is_active': False}
```

Comment: В админке джанго, запись появляется но отношение к info_court поле None???(